# Calling a javascript function in mvc 4 foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i want to call a jquery function in a MVC 4 razor syntax foreach loop,function must be called in every loop

here's my updated code

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<table>
<td>
          <div id="date">  

          <input id="datei" type="hidden" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hire_date)" />
          </div>
         <div id="datedis"></div>
        <script >
           GetDate()

        </script>

    </td>
```

this is Getdate function

```
 var GetDate = function()
{
    var date2 = new Date("2014-11-01")
    var dt = $("#datei").val();
    var dtx = new Date(Date.parse(dt));
    var datediff = date2 - dtx;

    var years = datediff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;
    var months = datediff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 31;

    var yeardisplay;
    var monthdisplay;

    if (years > 0) {
        yeardisplay = Math.floor(years);
        monthdisplay = Math.floor(months);

        $("#datedis").html(yeardisplay + "Years," + " " + monthdisplay + " Months");
    } else {
        monthdisplay = Math.floor(months);

        $("#datedis").html(monthdisplay + " Months");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Javascript function? What does it do, etc.

Comment: it is used for format a datetime

Comment: i have found a another way to do it..this way is more harder i just modified the data in controller

Comment: thats better anyway, embedding scripts calls in this manner is a horrible practice.

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <script>                

    GetDate();

    </script>  

}
```

Comment: i got this error when i run above code ReferenceError: GetDate is not defined

Comment: i have implemented the getdate function below in a script tag

Comment: it must defined before calling place it on top of view

Comment: it worked but only for 1st loop from 2nd loop functoin not working i have found a another way thanks

Comment: the function will be called in every loop the thing you did is in definition of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather then mixing the script with html. I would recommend you to write out the html and have the jQuery/javascript to iterate through it when the page is loaded. Let me know if you need any further help with it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Df7sk/)

Look at the demo, for html structure. But this is basically what I mean. You would have to modify it for you `GetDate()`, sorry for my lack of time to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = $('.container .date-container');

    $.each(obj, function (i, item) {
        //item here is each date-container (your case table)
        //so you can do what you like with it here
    });
});
```